# Using output of command to generate autocompletion commands for zsh

Tags: shell, autocomplete, zsh

Hey, I'm trying to get zsh to run a git command, and use the output to generate autocomplete possibilities.

The command I'm trying to run is

```
git log -n 2 --pretty=format:"'%h %an'"
```

And here's the code I'm using:

```
local lines words

lines=(${(f)$(git log -n 2 --pretty=format:"'%h %an'")})
words=${(f)$(_call_program foobar git log -n 2 --pretty=format:"%h")}

echo "Length of lines is " ${#lines[@]} " value is " ${lines}
echo "Length of words is " ${#words[@]} " value is " ${words}

compadd -d lines -a -- words
```

This doesn't work at all...it thinks that `words` is a single element and lines aren't getting printed properly at all.

However, when I try to setup an array of strings by hand, it all works.

```
local lines words

lines=('one two' 'three')
words=('one two' 'three')

echo "Length of lines is " ${#lines[@]} " value is " ${lines}
echo "Length of words is " ${#words[@]} " value is " ${words}

compadd -d lines -a -- words
```

Comment: Is that really a literal `words` and not `"$words[@]"` in the `compadd`?

Comment: @geekosaur Yes, it is. The `-a` option makes `compadd` look for specified array. And `"$words[@]"` is a bash code, though it may work in zsh due to the fact that zsh developers are concerned about compatibility with bash, sane zsh developer will write just `$words` instead of that (it works normally, no matter what symbols are in array values).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To force words being an array, you should use either

```
words=( ${(f)...} )
```

or

```
set -A words ${(f)...}
```

. If you use just `words=${(f)...}`, you will always get one value. By the way, why have you added parenthesis around `${(f)...}` when you were writing `lines` definition, but have not done it for `words`?

Also, there is another thing to concern: `${(f)$(...)}` should be replaced with `${(f)"$(...)"}`. It is some black magic here: I don't know why first one does emit a single scalar value, while second one does emit an array of scalar values, just was pointed to this fact by someone here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, ZyX, here's the final script for anyone who cares

```
local lines words

lines=(${(f)"$(git log -n 15 --pretty=format:"'%h - %an - %s'")"} )
words=(${(f)"$(git log -n 15 --pretty=format:"%h")"})

compadd -l -d lines -a -- words
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a more complicated situation.  I was trying to grep many files for a string, then edit the resulting list of files.  The use of ** and * wildcards didn't let the above solution work for me.  I did get it to work by breaking up into 2 steps:

```
> tmp=$(grep -l someString **/*.clj)
> fileList=( ${(f)tmp} )
```